# Addition of two rasters in PostGIS

Tags: raster, postgis, postgis-raster, map-algebra

I have two rasters (`prast` and `frast`) in PostGIS each with 1 band and with the similar extent and pixel characteristics (They were originally different bands of the same raster before I did some reclassifications of the bands). All I want is the addition of these two rasters. I want to ignore no data values when adding unless pixels from both rasters have no data values (represented by 255). I thought it will be a simple task. However, I am not getting the desired output

My attempt with `st_union`

```
SELECT
    st_union (st_addband(frast.rast, prast.rast), 'SUM') AS rast
FROM
    frast,
    prast
```

But this returns a raster with two bands and none of the bands gives the sum.

my attempt with `st_mapalgebra`

```
SELECT
    st_mapalgebra (frast.rast,
    prast.rast,
    '([rast1] + [rast2])',
    '16BUI',
    'UNION',
    '[rast2.val]',
    '[rast1.val]',
    255) AS rast
FROM
    frast,
    prast
```

This takes forever to run and the output file is huge (almost 100 times bigger than the result from attempt one). From the summary statistics, it doesn't look like it's the sum of two rasters.

What am I doing wrong?